# How to render raw HTML block from Rich Text Editor after Axios request?

Tags: node.js, django, vue.js, nuxt.js, rich-text-editor

So my backend is Django with Django Rest API and there I create my blog posts which are rendered in Nuxt page using "v-html" directive.

**Problem 1:** Uploaded images inside of Rich editor in Django is not rendering in Nuxt (Aim is to be able to add pictures in the middle of blog post)

**Problem 2:** Codeblocks (html code block with markdown) inserted in Rich Editor is being rendered in Nuxt without any styles, whereas the same codeblock being inserted as a Nuxt data object is rendered with styles. (Aim is to be able to insert codeblocks in rich editor so its rendered in Nuxt with styles)

As a rich text editor in Django Admin I use Django-Trumbowyg.

I searched everywhere, however couldn't find the **proper** solution! All the solutions I digged out in internet are "workarounds" and from my point of view its not the way it is supposed to be. I would more than glad if you could provide a reference if it's a duplicate or help me to find out a solid solution.

:)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say Nuxt data object? And it would be helpful if you could describe a workaround that you’ve tried and how it was not helpful, how you might like this to work otherwise.

Comment: By "Nuxt data object" I mean the variable containing html block  stored in data() which is processed in clientside. And regarding the workarounds I can't even find them again, but here is the similar problem: [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/freos8/are_reactive_components_from_html_strings/)